# Boostrap d-flex in a typescript application

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm using angular and bootstrap for developing an application. I have some issues regarding the layout. For example I have a component for navbar:

navbar.component.html

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top heigh">
    .... // navbar items, etc. 
  </nav>
</div>
```

app.componenent.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

I created another component. In that component until now I have the navbar because it is applied by the app.component. Further, I  added in the component a d-flex container:

```
<div class="d-flex"> My text </div>
```

I don't understand why this div is behind the navbar ? I can see the text only if I add some margins... 
I thought that these two d-flex containers should display one under another. Could you please tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

"My text" is behind your navbar because your nav has the `fixed-top` class.
You have to set height for your navbar and then add a padding in the div with your text:

navbar.component.html

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top heigh" style="height: 50px">
    .... // navbar items, etc. 
  </nav>
</div>
```

div in another component

```
<div class="d-flex" style="padding-top: 50px"> My text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't an issue with TypeScript, it's actually just a CSS issue, and it happens because your `.navbar` has the `.fixed-top` class.

This sets your navbar to `position: fixed; top: 0`, everything on you DOM that has `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` is taken out of the regular document flow, so other items that are positioned statically are not going to take those elements into consideration.

If you need you navbar to be fixed to the top, simply adding a `margin-top` property to the first item below will be enough to push it to where the navbar doesn't cover it

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
    .... // navbar items, etc.
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="d-flex" style="margin-top:50px;"> My text </div>
```